# Marp プレビューが Markdown プレビューのまま

Tags: vscode, markdown

VScode に Markdown を入れた環境に、Marp を追加しました。
Marp のエクスポートはできましたが、プレビューがスライド形式ではなく、Markdown のプレビューのままです。
Markdown と Marp の共存はできないのでしょうか？
どこかの設定でプレビューを切り替えられないでしょうか？

Comment: 「スライド形式」とは何を指すのでしょうか？設定に関しては, 拡張(Ctrl + Shift + X) から該当する拡張を選び, "機能のコントリビューション" で出るので参考に

Comment: スライド形式とは、Marp のプレビュー表示形式で、--- でページ区切りができます。追って「機能のコントリビューション」は調べてみます

Comment: 例えば [VS Code + Marp](https://qiita.com/tomo_makes/items/aafae4021986553ae1d8) の記事の, 先頭行近くの `marp: true` の記述では？

Comment: marp: true は書いているので、パワーポイント形式のエクスポートはできました。プレビューを１ページごとに表示したいです。

Comment: 思い出しましたが、パワーポイント形式にエクスポートはできましたが、１ページにすべて吐き出されていて、ページ区切りされていませんでした。 --- による改ページを認識していないようです

Comment: コメントで細々とやり取りするより、スライド原稿のソースやsettings.jsonの関連しそうな内容を質問に追記した方が早いのでは？

Answer (score 1):

お騒がせしましたが、解決しました。
拡張(Ctrl + Shift + X) から `Marp` を選択すると、「再読み込みが必要です」と出ていたのでこれを実行すると、プレビュー・アイコンが２つ出てきました。（下図の左から3つ目と4つ目）
[image: ←]

左のアイコンは従来のマークダウンプレビューでしたが、右のアイコンでスライド形式表示されました

[image: 右]

@oriri さんありがとうございました！